# NameError: name 'row' is not defined

Tags: python, pos-tagger

I am using the Python 3.6.1(IDLE) and counting the frequency of the pos_tag. My code is

```
import csv
import nltk
with open('data.csv', 'rt') as f:
   readerf = csv.reader(f)
from collections import Counter
Counter([j for i,j in pos_tag(row)])
```

I am getting the following error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:/Users/ABRAR/Google Drive/Tourism Project/TouristPython/POS_Tagging.py", line 7, in <module>
      Counter([j for i,j in pos_tag(row)])
NameError: name 'row' is not defined
```

However,the same code run correctly in the jupyter(web based).
Here is my sample data

[ab,
aback,
abandon,
abate,
abc,
ability,
able,
ablution,
abound,
abroad,
abruptly,
absence,
absolute,
absolutely,
absorb]

and here is the snap of jupyter
[code and answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5bgK9.png)

Comment: `NameError: name 'row' is not defined`.... it looks like the variable `row` is not defined. Where do you define it? And for that matter where is `pos_tag` defined?

Comment: I am new to python but the same code is working in jupyter. I dont know but I did not define it there either

Comment: Well then I don't know what jupyter is doing. As written, your snippet of code is invalid as you are missing the above defined variables.

Comment: why down vote? please

Comment: No, you must have defined it earlier in jupyter. As should be obvious, you can't refer to values you haven't defined.

Comment: there may be a chance that a cell from jupyter notebook is missing or row variable is defined somewhere in the same notebook. Jupyter notebook keeps everything in memory and hence it can access the old value of the row while standalone python code is giving error.

Comment: @CoryKramer that's why I added the snap of that code with the answer. Is it a reason for down vote

Comment: If jupyter is keeping history then, I think you are right. @ Vinay Pande, Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import csv
import nltk

f = open("data.csv","r")
readerf = csv.reader(f)
temp = []
for row in readerf:
    temp.append(postag(row)[1])

from collections import Counter
Counter(temp)
```

I think this will solve your problem